# form doesn't get submitted on an auto refreshed page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form-submit, page-refresh

I have web application in PHP and i need some variables in this page to get refreshed automatically. Therefore i have put that processing in another page - "test.php" - which gets loaded into this div every 10 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval( function ()
{
 $('#refresh').load('test.php').fadeIn("slow");
 }, 10000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="refresh">
</div>
</body></html>
```

The problem is that this page has a form which on clicking, doesn't not submit the values and do the processing as it is supposed to do. Without the auto refresh code, it works fine. How do i overcome this problem?

the test.php contains this form:

```
<form action="count.php" method="post">
<?php 

$votes = getVoteCount($popular[$i][1]); 

$voted=checkVoted($screenName,$id);?>

<td><img src="<?php echo $popular[$i][4]; ?>" width=60></td>
<td align="center"><CITE><?php echo "@".$username; ?></CITE>
                    <?php echo "<br >".$text.
                              "<br >".$votes." votes |";?>
    <?php 
    if($screenName!=$username && $voted==false){
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="addID" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $screenName;?>">
    <INPUT TYPE="image" src="images/vote.png" name='vote' ALT="Submit Form" onMouseOver="this.src='images/vote_link.png'"
    onMouseOut="this.src='images/vote.png'" width="35" height="20" title="Click to Vote!"></form>
    <?php }else if($voted){ ?>
    <img src="images/voted.png" width="35" height="20" title="You have already voted">
        <?php    } else{
    echo "<img src='images/authored.png' width='40' height='20'>";
    }?>
```

Comment: How did the loaded form looks like?

Comment: What are you using to submit? Javascript, form....?

Comment: @Muhammad: I have added in the form tag from the test.php page

Comment: @PFY - I am using form to submit

Comment: Try changing the input to a regular `img` tag and adding an onclick action to submit the form

Comment: I added this in the img tag - onclick="voteform.submit()" and I am getting this error - voteform.submit() is not a function. Do i need to add some javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're reloading the page with ajax requests you no longer can use

```
$("submit-button").click()
```

or

```
$("submit-button").submit();
```

You will need to use either jquery's live, delegate, or on to do this. (Live is no longer a recommended way of doing this.

```
$("body").on("click", "submit-button", function()
 {
     //execute code here
 });
```

or

```
$("body").on("submit", "submit-form", function()
 {
     //execute code here
 });
```